# They're mine as long as I come by latest Friday

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

> I only reserved the tickets, but they're mine as long as I come by **latest Friday**.

Hi. How do I express in a natural way that my deadline to pick up the tickets is Friday? 'Cause I'm pretty sure "latest Friday" isn't correct here.

Comment: "...as long as I collect them by Friday" (you could add "at the latest", but it isn't really necessary).

Comment: I agree with Kate, although I think "by Friday" leaves it a little unclear whether you need to collect them *before* Friday, whereas "Friday at the latest" makes it clearer that you can collect them *on* Friday.